# Updating Data Studio with new data from Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm new to Biq Query and Data Studio and so far have managed to get my data to display in Data Studio. The data is coming from my Firestore project. The problem is that as new data is added to Firestore I want that data to automatically show in Data Studio but not having any luck.

I noticed in Preview I get a warning message '200 row per page limit reached due to duplicate values or complex results. Displaying 2 results to reflect this.' I'm not sure if this is part of the problem or not.

I have set the freshness to every 15 minutes in Data Studio.

When I press 'Refresh Fields' in Data Studio, I get 'NO FIELD CHANGES WERE FOUND'.

I added two new test users to Firestore and then composed a new query in Big Query.

```
SELECT * from `myprojectname.Reports_user_details`
```

When I run the query it showed 2 new rows were added.

How can I get the two new users to show in Data Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Data studio is caching the data. At any time you need to refresh it there is a button.

[image]

Comment: I keep trying the refresh button but the new data doesn't load onto my table.

Comment: You didnát defined how you did the Firestore to BigQuery connection, I was assuming you installed: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export

Comment: I exported the collection into a bucket on Google Cloud Platform

Comment: Wow, that's ONE time only. So you need to export again and reimport again, or setup a pipeline to do that.

Comment: Ah I see. How do I set up a pipeline? Or is the best way of getting updated data to set up an Extension in Firebase?

Comment: Estension is real time, the pipeline is batched every X minutes, or every 60 minutes. Cloud Workflows is a great candidate to build the pipeline.

Comment: I've added the extension to my project but how do I get the update data this way?

Comment: in the extension page there are instructions how to setup the table, and VIEW example as well